# Convert code to new keras version (functional API) or how to concatenate 2 models

Tags: keras, keras-layer, keras-2

Megre doesn't work anymore. I tried the new functional API (concatenate, add, multiply) but it doesn't work for models. How to implement it?

```
lower_model = [self.build_network(self.model_config['critic_lower'], input_shape=(self.history_length, self.n_stock, 1)) 
                               for _ in range(1  + self.n_smooth + self.n_down)]
                merged = Merge(lower_model, mode='concat')
                # upper layer
                upper_model = self.build_network(self.model_config['critic_upper'],  model=merged)
                # action layer
                action = self.build_network(self.model_config['critic_action'], input_shape=(self.n_stock,), is_conv=False)
                # output layer
                merged = Merge([upper_model, action], mode='mul')
                model = Sequential()
                model.add(merged)
                model.add(Dense(1))
                return model
```

Comment: Please describe the problem completely, and show us what you tried with the functional API, and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot really give you the exact answer, because your question is not detailed enough, but I can provide you an example, where layers are concatenated. Common problem is to import Concatenate and use it as in previous versions.

```
nlp_input = Input(shape=(seq_length,), name='nlp_input')
meta_input = Input(shape=(10,), name='meta_input')
emb = Embedding(output_dim=embedding_size, input_dim=100, input_length=seq_length)(nlp_input)
nlp_out = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))(emb)
x = concatenate([nlp_out, meta_input])
x = Dense(classifier_neurons, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[nlp_input , meta_input], outputs=[x])
```

Comment: Well I posted the code in the old keras version and I want to compile it in the newest keras version:

Comment: And
`concatenate([upper_model, action])` does not work?

Comment: I tried the new functional api like concatenate but it doen't work. I read that the problem is that the new api works with tensors only not models. The problem is how to write merged = Merge(lower_model, mode='concat') with the latest keras version and also merged = Merge([upper_model, action], mode='mul')

Comment: I also tried merged = merge(lower_model, mod="cos", dot_axes=1) and got TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: build_network
Model= <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001E805FC6630>
build_network
build_network
Model= <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001E805FC6EF0>

Comment: lower_model= [<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001E805FC6630>, <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001E805FC6EF0>, <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001E8045C1F28>, <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001E808060E48>, .... And more...

Comment: You are trying to concatenate Sequential and Functional models? Try to call `concatenate([upper_model.model, action.model])` or look here
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10386

Comment: I tried merged = Concatenate()([lower_model.model]) and got this error:  merged = Concatenate()([lower_model.model])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty workaround to show how to get input and output tensors from models and use concatenate layers with them. Also to learn how to use `Dense` and other layers with tensors and create functional API models.

Ideally, you should rewrite everything that's inside `build_network` for clean and optimized code. (Perhaps this doesn't even work depending on the content of this function, but this is the idea)

```py
lower_model = [self.build_network(
                  self.model_config['critic_lower'], 
                  input_shape=(self.history_length, self.n_stock, 1)) 
               for _ in range(1  + self.n_smooth + self.n_down)]

#for building models you need input and output tensors
lower_inputs = [model.input for model in lower_model]
lower_outputs = [model.output for model in lower_model]
    #these lines assume each model in the list has only one input and output

#using a concatenate layer on a list of tensors
merged_tensor = Concatenate()(lower_outputs) #or Concatenate(axis=...)(lower_outputs)


#this is a workaround for compatibility. 
#ideally you should work just with tensors, not create unnecessary intermediate models
merged_model = Model(lower_inputs, merged_tensor) #make model from input tensors to outputs

# upper layer
upper_model = self.build_network(self.model_config['critic_upper'],  model=merged_model)

# action layer
action = self.build_network(self.model_config['critic_action'], input_shape=(self.n_stock,), is_conv=False)

# output layer - get the output tensors from the models
upper_out = upper_model.output
action_out = action.output

#apply the Multiply layer on the list of tensors
merged_tensor = Multiply()([upper_out, action_out])

#apply the Dense layer on the merged tensor
out = Dense(1)(merged_tensor)

#get input tensors to create a model
upper_iputs = upper_model.inputs #should be a list   
action_inputs = action.inputs #if not a list, append to the previous list

inputs = upper_inputs + action_inputs
model = Model(inputs, out)

return model
```

Comment: I get undefined Model and merged in merged_model = Model(lower_inputs, merged). Am I missing an import?

Comment: Exactly what I fixed in the answer.

Comment: Ok now I get error in 
upper_model = self.build_network(self.model_config['critic_upper'],  model=merged_model) 
ValueError: Layer model_1 expects 11 inputs, but it received 1 input tensors. Input received: [<tf.Tensor 'model_1_input:0' shape=(?, 10, 3, 1) dtype=float32>]

Comment: Now it's up to you to work `build_network` properly. I can't help if the code is hidden. If it's expecting tensors instead of models, there is no point in merging the tensors.

Comment: def build_network(self, conf, model=None, input_shape=None, is_conv=True):
        """Build network"""
        _model = model
        model = Sequential()
        if _model is None:
            model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x,  input_shape=input_shape))
        else:
            model.add(_model)
It fails model.add(_model)

Comment: Rewrite everything. Use only functional API, forget about sequentials and merges. This seems a lot of trouble now, but it's the best for all your future projects.

Comment: I am new to this and rewriting everything is beyond me. There must be a relatively simple solution to implement Merge concat and mul in the new version of Keras.

Comment: It is simple. Just get the input/output tensors and pass them through layers, but you haven't shown any code, it's impossible to know what is happening in `build_network`. But it's mixing things, models and tensors and this is more confusing than just building a new model from scratch.

Comment: I posted a new thread with the full code actor+critic+build network.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406981/convert-old-keras2-code-to-new-keras2